# How to read value of an INode?

Tags: c#, dotnetrdf

I know you two ways, but don't work as I want:

**1. [INode].ToString();**

This returns the value in my node plus a "^^[predicate uri]", like this;

```
random node value.^^http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string
```

**2. [INode].ReadXml(Xml reader);** I don't know how to use, coz I can't find any examples.

Is there a way of retrieving only the value of the node?

Or is the "XmlRead()" methode what I need? How do I use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the `NodeType` you can cast to the appropriate interface and then access the value e.g.

```
switch (node.NodeType)
{
  case NodeType.Literal:
    return ((ILiteralNode)node).Value;
  case NodeType.Uri:
    return ((IUriNode)node).Uri.ToString();
  // etc.
}
```

Or you might want to use `node.AsValuedNode().AsString()` if you are sure that your node is a literal

Note that the `ReadXml()`/`WriteXml()` methods are for .Net XML serialisation and are not intended for general use.

Comment: This helped a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To get content you should use `WriteXml` instead of `ReadXml` function

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
var xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings
{   // It's required in my case but maybe not in your try different settings
    ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Auto
};
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb, xmlWriterSettings))
    rdfType.WriteXml(writer);
var result = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have misundestood the XmlReader and XmlWriter, also understand the way of use, but don't seem to get it working.
This message I get:

```
InvalidOperationException: This XmlWriter does not accept Attribute at this state Content.
```

I suppose I do need to tweak the XmlWritterSettings in order to make it work.

I don't see any documantion on the required XmlWritterSettings for reading the DotNetRDF INodes, so I shall use the "ToString()" for now.

this is the part of the RDF/XML that the node holds:

```
    <property:Paragraph rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Geef houvast.</property:Paragraph>
```

Isn't there some other way to extract the "Geef houvast." between the element?

**Thanks for helping me understand the XmlReader/XmlWriter now!**